# How to make cloudfront not cache any html file

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a React application served on S3, with CloudFront. I know it's a common question on how to not cache the `index.html` file. I could make it work changing the Behavior of CloudFront distribution, but the issue I am facing is different.

Basically, on a SPA all URL are redirected to `/`, so React knows how to serve each one. My issue is that when I try to access `https://mywebsite.com/login`, a `login.html` is served from CloudFront (even if I don't have this file). This file is actually `index.html`. My issue is that the Behavior of CloudFront distribution doesn't work for this path, and a cached `index.html` file is served.

I tried to change the Path Pattern to be `/*.html`, but this is not a valid config in CloudFront.

My question is: what's the best way to tell CloudFront that I don't want to cache **any** html files, and that I want to hit S3 on every request of a html file?

Thank you!